# What is difference between these two pieces of code when we do operator overloading?

Tags: c++, class, object, temporary

Code 1:

```
class CVector {
public:
    int x, y;
    CVector() {};
    CVector(int a, int b) :x(a), y(b) {}
};

CVector operator- (const CVector& lhs, const CVector& rhs)
{
    CVector temp;
    temp.x = lhs.x - rhs.x;
    temp.y = lhs.y - rhs.y;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    CVector foo(2, 3);
    CVector bar(3, 2);
    CVector result;
    result = foo - bar;
    cout << result.x << ',' << result.y << endl;
}
```

Code 2:

```
class CVector {
public:
    int x, y;
    CVector() {};
    CVector(int a, int b) :x(a), y(b) {}
};

CVector operator- (const CVector& lhs, const CVector& rhs)
{
    return CVector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y);
}

int main()
{
    CVector foo(2, 3);
    CVector bar(3, 2);
    CVector result;
    result = foo - bar;
    cout << result.x << ',' << result.y << endl;
}
```

These two pieces of code operate identically. I want to know why we can write `CVector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y)`. What does it mean? What happens when we use a class without a name?

Comment: The 2nd snippet uses the **parameterized constructor** in the return statement `return CVector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y)`

Comment: For the absolutely *full answer*, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs .

Comment: No different from any other type. Is there a difference between: `int a = 3; return a;` and `return 3`;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why we can write `CVector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y)`. What does it mean? What happens when we use a class without a name?

The expression `CVector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y)` uses the **pameterized constructor** `CVector::CVector(int, int)` to construct a `CVector` by passing the arguments `lhs.x - rhs.x` and `lhs.y - rhs.y`. Just like `CVector foo(2, 3);` and  `CVector bar(3, 2)` uses the parameterized constructor, the expression `CVector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y)` also uses the parameterized ctor.

You can confirm this by adding a `cout` inside the parameterized constructor as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

class CVector {
public:
    int x, y;
    CVector() {};
    CVector(int a, int b) :x(a), y(b) {
        std::cout<<"paremterized ctor used"<<std::endl;
        }
};

CVector operator- (const CVector& lhs, const CVector& rhs)
{
    return CVector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y); //this uses the parameterized ctor
}

int main()
{
    CVector foo(2, 3);
    CVector bar(3, 2);
    CVector result;
    result = foo - bar;
    std::cout << result.x << ',' << result.y << std::endl;
}
```

The [output](https://onlinegdb.com/hdE3psnBE) of the above program is:

```
paremterized ctor used
paremterized ctor used
paremterized ctor used
-1,1
```

Notice in the output shown above, the third call to the parameterized ctor is due to the return statement `return CVector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y);`

Comment: So, if I write as an integer type, is CVector(lhs.x-rhs.x, lhs.y-rhs.y) equal to int (10)? just for example.

Comment: Just like this.
int a(3);
int (3);

CVector A(3,4);
CVector (3,4);

Comment: @심민기 For example, `CVector(3,4)`, `CVector(10,1)`, `CVector(1,1)` all uses the [parameterized ctor](http://www.trytoprogram.com/cplusplus-programming/constructors/#Parameterized_constructor). All of these create an object of type `CVector` using the parameterized ctor. Just like, inside the `main` function, the statement `CVector foo(2, 3);` creates an object of type `CVector` named `foo` by passing the arguments 2 and 3 to the parameterized ctor.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have two more questions: Is CVector(3,4) a temporary object that does not have a name and only has x and y values? Does CVector a = CVector(3,4) makes a.x=3 and a.y=4?

Comment: @심민기 `CVector(3,4);` creates an *unnamed* temporary object that will be destroyed at the end of the full expression. On the other hand, `CVector foo(3,4);` creates a *named* object that will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: So does CVector a = CVector(3,4) means allocating each values of member variables of CVector(3,4) to a?

Comment: @심민기 `CVector a = CVector(3,4);` is [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) and uses the copy-constructor. Here, `a` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.